# Fixed menu does not keep fixed when applying media query

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I was trying to reproduce [this tutorial](http://osvaldas.info/drop-down-navigation-responsive-and-touch-friendly) for a responsive menu. It all worked well, but I tried to keep the menu fixed on the top of the page for one of my projects. Unfortunately the hidden menu when fixed, do not change the z-index after the hover.

```
#icon_cont  ul{
    background-color: #cccccc;
    margin-top: 75px;
    z-index:-2; /**THIS DOES NOT APPLY**/
    position: absolute;
    top:100%;
    padding: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

I tried in every way but it didn't work at all.

You can see in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/evarildo/o0L4s9z5/) that when the container has relative position, it works, but when it's with the fixed position, the menu does not stay behind the other elements.

Appreciate, any help!

Comment: Where are you applying the media query here ?

Comment: Sorry, removed for better understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because you're applying `postion: fixed;` to the element. Fixing a position pushes to the front of the z-index stack. Here are the basic rules for understanding how the stacking order works:

> 1. The stacking context’s root element
> 2. Positioned elements (and their children) with negative z-index values (higher values are stacked in front of lower values; elements with the same value are stacked according to appearance in the HTML)
> 3. Non-positioned elements (ordered by appearance in the HTML)
> 4. Positioned elements (and their children) with a z-index value of auto (ordered by appearance in the HTML)
> 5. Positioned elements (and their children) with positive z-index values (higher values are stacked in front of lower values; elements with the same value are stacked according to appearance in the HTML)

(*Taken from **Philip Walton**'s invaluable post, ["What No One Told You About Z-Index"](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/)*)

When you apply `position: fixed;` to an element, it sits in front of all relatively position items. **Z-index values are relative to their "stack", not globally.**

> Every stacking context has a single HTML element as its root element. When a new stacking context is formed on an element, that stacking context confines all of its child elements to a particular place in the stacking order. **That means that if an element is contained in a stacking context at the bottom of the stacking order, there is no way to get it to appear in front of another element in a different stacking context that is higher in the stacking order, even with a z-index of a billion!**
>
> New stacking contexts can be formed on an element in one of three ways:
>
> - When an element is the root element of a document (the `<html>` element)
> - When an element has a position value other than `static` and a z-index value other than `auto`
> - When an element has an `opacity` value less than 1

***(Emphasis mine)***